# text under the section title without spacing

Tags: spacing, section-titles

I would like to have space 1em to all the text/paragraphs under the section name directly because there is no change even after using \parindent. And help is appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}

%paragraph indentation
\setlength{\parindent}{1em} 

%paragraph spacing
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}
This is another paragraph, contains some text to test the paragraph interlining, paragraph indentation and some other features. Also, is easy to see how new paragraphs are defined by simply entering a double blank space.

This is another paragraph, contains some text to test the paragraph interlining, paragraph indentation and some other features. Also, is easy to see how new paragraphs are defined by simply entering a double blank space.

\end{document}
```

**The output:**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you tried loading the `indentfirst` packagea?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your objective correctly, I believe it can be achieved by loading the [indentfirst](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/indentfirst) package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{indentfirst} % <-- new
\setlength{\parindent}{1em} 
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

This is another paragraph, contains some text to test the paragraph interlining, paragraph indentation and some other features. Also, is easy to see how new paragraphs are defined by simply entering a double blank space.

This is another paragraph, contains some text to test the paragraph interlining, paragraph indentation and some other features. Also, is easy to see how new paragraphs are defined by simply entering a double blank space.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that exactly what I want, thank you.